# How to test my function when using INPUT_POST?

Tags: php, function, sanitization

I use `filter_input_array` PHP function when sanitizing data inputs in my application.  Consider example below:

```
public function acquireData()
{
    $args = array(
        'model' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    );

    //function that sanitizes input from POST
    $output = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args);

    return $output;
}
```

It works fine when I read live POST data from a web browser.  But when I want to pass in another array for the purposes of testing I struggle to find a solution.

i.e. using my own array does not work and produces empty `$output`:

```
$myInputArray = array('model' => 'ABC'); //with same parameters as $_POST
$output = filter_input_array($myInputArray, $args);
//$output is null;
```

**Note**

I want to specifically use `INPUT_POST` construct.  Or get an answer "it is not possible" or "you can only seek work-arounds".

i.e. using `filter_var_array` is a work-around, because it does not use `INPUT_POST`.  Example work-around below:

```
$output = filter_var_array($_POST, $args);
```

Comment: What's preventing you from testing by using a POST? And you may want to mention any problems you've had using [`filter_var_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php), assuming you've tried that...

Comment: I suppose my question is more so this -- is `filter_input_array` a useless function?  Certainly it has its uses but it seems to be too specific and if I can use `filter_var_array` any time I need `filter_input_array`,, I see `filter_input_array` as basically useless.  I was wondering if it was the case

Answer (score 0):

Until I know better, there only seems to be a work-around:

```
$output = filter_var_array($_POST, $args)
```

In other words, when you want to test using your own array, either write another function to sanitize inputs for your own array, or use `filter_var_array` instead of `filter_input_array`.

Answer (score 0):

`filter_input_array` appears to be just a convenience function. Instead of providing the specific variable containing the inputs, you provide a constant that specifies one of a standard set of global variables that can be filtered automatically. So

```
filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args);
```

is equivalent to:

```
filter_var_array($_POST, $args);
```